# SFTP Client - Problem Reading the output from pipe Delphi7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

This is my code that reads the contents of an SFTP server via pipes and puts it in my program UI. I have two such codes. The first does this for the ParentFolder, and the other for all other Subdirectories.

But I have a problem. After doing 5-6 operations going from folder to folder, or just browsing through the folders, my program stops updating the ListBox or stops showing the content in the folders. Then I have to wait 20-30 seconds, and then when I press Refresh the button starts working again for 5-6 operations.

I have 2 procedures:

- 1st `UpdateFileList` to update the parent folder
- 2nd `UpdateRemoteFile` to update all the subdirectories

I put in debug messages. Everything works perfect, I can upload, download, delete, and then suddenly after a few operations the output string goes to: `Fatal Error`. And then to: `Network error: Software caused connection abort`.

There is no network error, or problem with the administrators. When I use WINSCP and browse fast, there is no problem.

```
procedure TForm1.UpdateFileList(NewFile: string = '');
var
  CommandLine: string;
  ListTheFiles: string;
  StartupInfo: TStartupInfo;
  ProcessInfo: TProcessInformation;
  SecurityAttr: TSecurityAttributes;
  ReadPipe, WritePipe: THandle;
  Buffer: array[0..8191] of AnsiChar;
  BytesRead: DWORD;
  OutputString: string;
  FileList: TStringList;
  i: Integer;
  WasOK: Boolean;
  SelectedFolder: string;
begin
  if ListRemote.ItemIndex >= 0 then
  begin
    SelectedFolder := ListRemote.Items[ListRemote.ItemIndex];
    if Pos('Directory:', SelectedFolder) > 0 then
    begin
      SelectedFolder := Copy(SelectedFolder, 12, MaxInt);
      SelectedFolder := Trim(SelectedFolder);
    end;
  end;

  ListRemote.Items.BeginUpdate;
  listRemote.Items.Clear;
  CommandLine := 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pscp.exe';
  ListTheFiles := '-sftp -P ' + lblPort.Text + ' -pw ' + lblPassword.Text + ' -ls ' + lblUserName.Text + '@' + lblHostName.Text + ':/home/' + lblUserName.Text + '/' + SelectedFolder;
  CommandLine := CommandLine + ' ' + ListTheFiles;

  listRemote.Items.Add('Directory: ' + 'home/' + lblUserName.Text);

  if FProcessInfo.hProcess <> 0 then
  begin
    TerminateProcess(FProcessInfo.hProcess, 0);
    CloseHandle(FProcessInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(FProcessInfo.hThread);
    FProcessInfo.hProcess := 0;
  end;

  // Create pipes for reading the output of the command
  SecurityAttr.nLength := SizeOf(TSecurityAttributes);
  SecurityAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor := nil;
  SecurityAttr.bInheritHandle := True;
  if not CreatePipe(ReadPipe, WritePipe, @SecurityAttr, 0) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Failed to create pipe: ' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
    Exit;
  end;

  FillChar(StartupInfo, SizeOf(StartupInfo), 0);
  StartupInfo.cb := SizeOf(StartupInfo);
  StartupInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW or STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
  StartupInfo.wShowWindow := SW_HIDE;
  StartupInfo.hStdInput := GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
  StartupInfo.hStdOutput := WritePipe;
  StartupInfo.hStdError := WritePipe;

  if CreateProcess(nil, PChar(CommandLine), nil, nil, True, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, nil, nil, StartupInfo, ProcessInfo) then
  begin
    CloseHandle(WritePipe);

    // Read the output of the command
    repeat
      WasOK := ReadFile(ReadPipe, Buffer, SizeOf(Buffer), BytesRead, nil);
      if BytesRead > 0 then
      begin
        Buffer[BytesRead] := #0;
        OutputString := OutputString + StringReplace(Buffer, #13#10, #10, [rfReplaceAll]); // replace Windows-style line endings with Unix-style
      end;
    until not WasOK or (BytesRead = 0);

    WaitForSingleObject(ProcessInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);

    // Process the OutputString for folders and files
    FileList := TStringList.Create;
    try
      FileList.Text := OutputString;

      for i := 0 to FileList.Count - 1 do
      begin
       // if (FileList[i][1] = 'd') or (FileList[i][1] = '-') then // check if the line contains a file or folder
       // begin
          ListRemote.Items.Add(ExtractFileName(Trim(Copy(FileList[i], 56, Length(FileList[i]) - 55))));// extract the file or folder name
          ListRemote.Update;
          Application.ProcessMessages;
      //  end;
      end;
    finally
      FileList.Free;
    end;

    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(ProcessInfo.hThread);
    CloseHandle(ReadPipe);
  end;

  ListRemote.Items.EndUpdate;
end;
```

Comment: 'Software caused connection abort' is often a timeout

Comment: ok but what causes the timeoout

Comment: This work well for me https://github.com/superflexible/TGPuttyLib

Comment: Have you read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output) yet? You are not preparing your pipe correctly. In particular, DO NOT let the child process inherit the *read* end of your pipe, only the *write* end. You can limit which handles the child process actually inherits, either via `SetHandleInformation()`, or better by passing a `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_LIST` to `CreateProcess()` (see [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111216-00/?p=8873)).

Comment: if not SetHandleInformation(ReadPipe, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0) then
begin
  ShowMessage('Failed to set handle information: ' + SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
  Exit;
end;

Added this, but still doesnt help.

Comment: Probably not related to your problem, but I see a few mistakes in the code shown: 1) `ListRemote.Items.(Begin|End)Update` should be in a `try..finally`; 2) a buffer overflow occurs when writing `#0` to `Buffer` if `ReadFile` reads exactly `Sizeof(Buffer)` number of bytes; 3) no need to replace `CRLF` with `LF` when parsing `OutputString` as `TStringList` treats both types of line breaks equally; 4) you are leaking both pipe handles if `CreateProcess` fails